# Every installation on desktop asks for passwords that I never set in the first place

Tags: login, password, security

Everytime I boot up and try to log in using ubuntu, it asks for a username and password: which I have never set in the first place. So I log in under guest account. But when I try to change ANYTHING AT ALL, it asks for root password, or authentication password, or admin approval, or some variation thereof. But of course none of the passwords I attempt work, because I never set them in the first place. I've already uninstalled and reinstalled the OS, but it fixed nothing. Help?

Comment: When you install Ubuntu you should get a screen like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eTBJs.jpg if you don't get it and don't set a password you can't go forward. Therefore, you have not installed Ubuntu properly.

Answer (score 0):

During the install , and when you get to the screen that asks for your username and machine name , you should set a simple password, and tick the check box that says  login automatically , this way you will not have to type this password during login but it is always require for installing or modifying critical aspects of the OS, so you should set it